# Update table with data from same table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-update

Trying to write a query to update a table with data from the same table.

Basically we have two types of data in this table, budget and forecast, split up by customer, product, fiscal year and month.

A sample of the data would be as follows:

```
CustomerCosts
CustomerNo     Product     FiscalYear    Month    DataType    DataField    Q    R    G
CU01           REG         2014          1        Budget      Commission   10   2    20
CU01           REG         2014          1        Budget      Warehouse    5    5    25
CU01           REG         2014          2        Budget      Commission   30   1    30
CU01           REG         2014          2        Budget      Warehouse    12   2    24
CU01           REG         2014          1        Forecast    Commission   10   2    20
CU01           REG         2014          1        Forecast    Warehouse    5    5    25
CU01           REG         2014          2        Forecast    Commission   30   1    30
CU01           REG         2014          2        Forecast    Warehouse    12   2    24
```

Basically users are going to want to copy from one DataType to another.  For example, copy 2014 Budget into 2014 Forecast.

I came up with this query but while it seems to work the row updated count shows more rows are being updated than should be.

```
UPDATE CustomerCosts 
SET CustomerCosts.Q = f.Q, 
CustomerCosts.R = f.R,
CustomerCosts.G = f.G
FROM CustomerCosts
JOIN CustomerCosts f
ON CustomerCosts.CustomerNo = f.CustomerNo AND 
CustomerCosts.Product = f.Product AND 
CustomerCosts.Month = f.Month AND 
CustomerCosts.DataField = f.DataField
WHERE CustomerCosts.FiscalYear = 2014 AND 
CustomerCosts.DataType = N'Forecast' AND 
f.FiscalYear = 2014 AND
f.DataType = N'Budget'
```

Do I have this query right or am I missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I it looks OK to me. But to be sure it is always good idea to make a test. Copy table CustomerCosts into a new temp table using

```
SELECT * INTO Test_CustomerCosts FROM CustomerCosts
```

After that try update (change script so it works on Test table) and see results.

Try to modify your query to select:

```
select 
CustomerCosts.*, f.*
FROM CustomerCosts
JOIN CustomerCosts f ON 
  CustomerCosts.CustomerNo = f.CustomerNo AND 
  CustomerCosts.Product = f.Product AND 
  CustomerCosts.Month = f.Month AND 
  CustomerCosts.DataField = f.DataField
WHERE 
  CustomerCosts.FiscalYear = 2014 AND 
  CustomerCosts.DataType = N'Forecast' AND 
  f.FiscalYear = 2014 AND
  f.DataType = N'Budget'
```

to see whole picture.

Comment: I did and in my test table I had 20 test records, eight Budget,  eight Forecast and four that shouldn't be updated.  QA shows 10 rows affected when it should only be eight.  Checking the data I don't see any other rows updated than the eight that should have been but those extra two worry me.

Comment: You have `DataField` - `"Commission"` and `"Warehouse"` - that is the reason for duplicates. May be you have to add that field also in the JOIN CLAUSE or in the WHERE CLAUSE.

Comment: Correct, then check if you have duplicate rows in general. Which is your Primary key. If you have 2 equal rows then in update you will see 2 rows instead of one. All other seems fine and this is the thing that comes to my mind in this case. Also, when having initial table you can check is the calculations are correct.

Comment: The primary key is customerno, product, fiscalyear, month, datatype and datafield.  Here's the test data I am working with: http://jmp.sh/b/jk4ffM4VU6lDZfaHIWDz

Comment: I checked your every row (using the select query I posted) and see that there are matches for every row and the rows are 10 (10 rows x 2 = 20 rows). Only thing that I noticed is that you have 2 rows with 0. Because you do not have where clause restricting 0s you will have update them also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40839/discussion-between-bogdan-bogdanov-and-tom)

Comment: Actually I see the issue now, there is no issue.  It's working as it should.  Thanks!